# Turning off +6 enchantment global message in Tera?

Tags: tera

In Tera there is a big global alert when someone on the server enchants an item to +6. With several people accomplishing this feat each minute the alerts get annoying fast.

Is there a way to turn off the enchantment alerts?

Comment: As I'm not playing this game - WHY is there a GLOBAL message for this?!

Comment: A very good question. Perhaps there is a reason to be interested when every Joe and his grandmother enchants something. If there is, I would like to know too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately currently there is no way to disable these announcements. (I assume you are asking about the EU or NA version of the game)

Comment: Yes, it's the EU version. That's a shame, but browsing the forums a bit, it seems I'm not the only one noticing this. Hoping for a fix sooner rather than later then.

Answer (score 1):

It should be mentioned that in the US/EU beta, +6 was considered a very high enchantment level, and thus worthy of announcement.

In the live version, this has been disabled. (otherwise the spam would be constant)

On the other hand, +9 and above do seem to still have a global announcement.